# How many users/load can the rest API handle?

Tags: api, rest-api

Can the Wordpress rest API be used by thousands  of public users at the same time or is it limited for only developers to use? I want to use the API to serve content to thousands of users, but am finding that currently it is slow in pulling data from the server, I.e. images, etc.

Comment: sorry but as it is right now this is a pointless question. The performance will depend on the hardware and caching you will apply. In theory all the people on earth can use a site if enough resources is put into it

Answer (score 1):

> Can the Wordpress rest API be used by thousands of public users at the same time

Public users can use the REST API yes, though their access will be more restricted, e.g. you can see my sites rest API at `tomjn.com/wp-json`, but good luck trying to create a post without a login :)

> or is it limited for only developers to use?

As I mentioned, some endpoints require authenticated access, e.g. modifying and creating posts. Adding your own endpoints you can configure this

> I want to use the API to serve content to thousands of users, but am finding that currently it is slow in pulling data from the server

Yes, there are websites powered entirely by the REST API with thousands of concurrent users, but don't expect a shared hosting setup to be able to handle it.

REST API calls still take time and system resources, and if you can't serve the front page to 1000 users at the same time, the REST API won't be much different.

So the real answer depends on how well your site is built and the hardware object cache, and caching mechanisms backing it up

> I.e. images, etc.

REST APIs return JSON data, sometimes XML. They don't return images. Your JSON response might contain a HTML fragment, but any images referenced are just referenced. The same way PHP sending an image tag is just referencing them.

If you're hoping to send entire HTML pages via the REST API, as if it was the frontend, then you've got the wrong end of the stick. The REST API is not intended for humans. JS calls to your site, remote requests, tools etc, but not real people visiting.

Sites that use the REST API will send over a page, and that page will then make calls in JS to the API to fill in the gaps.

Comment: By images I mean the featured image on the post. Can this be served to thousands of users concurrently without lag?

Comment: There will always be lag, and the amount of lag will depend on the server you power your site with. There is no such thing as lag free. And again, REST API endpoints don't serve images. You can return the ID of the featured image, or the URL, but why would you want to do that, just bundle the information with the post when you retrieve it. Throw in a suitable caching solution and you're done.

Comment: Just don't ask questions like "will it work", else the only answer that can ever be marked as correct is "It depends", because it's not that simple. I'd need a full codebase and the specs of your server, and wether it's shared or not to be able to tell. Yes it will work, but will it scale to thousands of concurrent users? Who knows, you haven't provided enough info and the only way to guarantee it is to try it. A lot of servers would fall over serving `readme.html` to 1000 users, and that doesn't even execute PHP!